# Why can't I release my CTFramesetter without the app crashing?

Tags: ipad, memory-management, ios, nsattributedstring, core-text

I'm building an iPad app which renders pages of text from an NSAttributedString. I create a framesetter like this:

```
- (void)renderTextFromAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)string
{
    CFAttributedStringRef attrString = (CFAttributedStringRef)string;
    framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
    CFRelease(attrString);
```

... then the code adds new page views, one by one, and passes the framesetter pointer off to each one to render each page, until there are no characters left:

```
- (void)drawNewPage
{
    CTSinglePageView *newPage = [[CTSinglePageView alloc] initWithFrame:newFrame];
    newPage.delegate = self;
    [newPage renderWithFramesetter:framesetter fromIndex:currentIndex margins:self.margins];
    [self addSubview:newPage];
    [newPage release];
    currentPage ++;
```

... etc etc. Now this all works great, rendering the pages and showing the formatted text perfectly. However, at the end of the render process, I've still got a CTFramesetter which needs clearing, so I can build the next set of pages. However, if I do

```
    if(framesetter) CFRelease(framesetter);
```

at the end of the process, the CTFramesetter is released (obviously) and the program crashes! BUT... If I don't release the framesetter, I eventually get rather large memory leaks and the program bails out.

Why is the release causing a crash? With NSZombieEnabled turned on, the error message I get is:

> *** -[NSConcreteAttributedString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xed20270

Any help given is of course greatly received! We are currently up against a deadline here, if I could add a bounty now I would! **Anyone with a good answer will be rewarded a bounty after the 2 day window has elapsed.** :-)

Comment: more code which reveals more of the structure would be helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're supposed to be releasing attrString? That doesn't look right. I wonder if that's causing the crash later when releasing framesetter.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Sorry I had to go back and check, this question was asked a couple of months ago now and I forgot to close it off! Yes... The attrString wasn't supposed to have been released because I wasn't retaining it. The app has since been submitted and approved :-) but thanks for the help!